# Is it possible to generate Openapi spec file from the another spec with slight modifications?

Tags: java, swagger, openapi

Suppose I have Openapi specification file (api-docs.yml). I need to create a copy of it with:

1. different `servers` block
2. filtered `paths` by tag (with removing unnecessary schemas)

Do any solutions exist to make such things, or it's only possible to write your own parser?

I'm using Java so Java-based solutions (maven plugins etc.) are preferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do any solutions exist to make such things, or it's only possible to write your own parser?

There are [OpenAPI parsers](https://openapi.tools/#parsers) for various programming languages. In Java, you can use [Swagger Parser](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-parser/) - use version 2.x for OpenAPI 3.0.x or v. 1.x for OpenAPI 2.0 (`swagger: '2.0'`).

I think [openapi-filter](https://github.com/Mermade/openapi-filter) can filter content by tags, among other things.

You can also try using a YAML parser/processor such as [yq](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/).